# Failing to connect to tug.org

Tags: repositories, resources

I have been trying to connect to the [Tex Users Group (TUG)](http://www.tug.org/) website for the past few days with no success at all. I keep getting the **connection has timed out** error message.
I was wondering if someone in the TeX community knows what is going on, perhaps they have changed their domain or maybe they are updating their servers - I have no idea. Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: works for me (now), though i can't speak to "recent past" connectivity, since i've not needed it for some time.

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: @daleif -- but you've no "hop" to to site, i thought ... or do i remember incorrectly?

Comment: works for me as well. A useful site for testing these things is http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.tug.org  as that will report to you whether _it_ can see the site you are interested in.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - thanks for the link. I've checked it out and it seems it's just me. I wonder why me! All other websites work fine, as I'm using the same internet connection to send this comment!

Comment: @wasteofspace true, I'm one the same (internal) network. The university have had some long response times at various times lately (perhaps due to changes to the network?) so you may have asked for the page at a bad time.